# Header TextView With RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` + `CardView` to show a list of text now I am trying to add a plain `TextView` header to the top of the `RecyclerView` so I have the two layouts inside the adapter but now it shows like this in the app:

[image]

And it must look like this:

[image]

So problem is probably with the `getItemCount` and `getItemViewType` what must I change so the header only shows once followed by the `CardViews`.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int LAYOUT_ONE  = 0;
private static final int LAYOUT_TWO = 1;

List<AdapterData> mItems;

public Adapter() {
    super();
    mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    AdapterData data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setCode("dummytext");
    data.setResult("dummytext");
    mItems.add(data);

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch ( viewType ) {

        case LAYOUT_ONE: return new ViewHolderFirst(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.top_textview, parent, false));

        case LAYOUT_TWO: return new ViewHolderSecond(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, parent, false));
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {

        case LAYOUT_ONE:
            ViewHolderFirst viewHolderFirst = (ViewHolderFirst)holder;

            break;

        case LAYOUT_TWO:
            ViewHolderSecond viewHolderSecond = (ViewHolderSecond)holder;
            AdapterData data = mItems.get(position);
            viewHolderSecond.code.setText(data.getCode());
            viewHolderSecond.result.setText(data.getResult());

            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}



class ViewHolderFirst extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView header;

    public ViewHolderFirst(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        header = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.header_textview);

    }
}

class ViewHolderSecond extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView code;
    public TextView result;

    public ViewHolderSecond(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        code = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sims_code);
        result = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sims_result);

    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in getItemViewType() try this

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return (position==0) ? 0 : 1;   //try this line
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot works just it removes the 1st cardview for some reason